# VBA coding - Generating Random Variable

Tags: vba, excel, markov-chains

I want to write a code into a VBA excel. I have prepared the algorithm that is shown below, but I do not know exactly how I will write it in VBA :/
Can someone help me with this?

1) Assign initial values: Current is 1, Year is 0, Result is empty string.

2) Generate a random variate u from U(0,1);

3) If Current is 1, and u ≤ 0.23, assign 0 to Current. If Current is 0, and u > 0.86, assign 1 to Current. Otherwise do nothing.

4) Increase Year by 1. Write Current at the end of the Result string.

5) If Year less than cell("A2").value, go to step (2). Otherwise return Result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a UDF (user-defined function) that can be used directly on the spreadsheet:

```
Function Chain(years As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long, result As String
    Dim u As Single
    Dim current As Long

    Randomize
    Application.Volatile

    current = 1
    For i = 1 To years
        u = Rnd()
        If (current = 1 And u <= 0.23) Or (current = 0 And u > 0.86) Then
            current = 1 - current
        End If
        result = result & current
    Next i
    Chain = result
End Function
```

`year` is just a counter and your algorithm in effect describes a simple for-loop. In VBA it is more idiomatic to loop from 1 to n than 0 to n-1 for a simple counter -- though this is mostly a matter of taste. Also -- I changed `year` to `i` to prevent accidental shadowing of the built-in function `year()`

VBA has natural default values for variables, hence I didn't need to explicitly initialize `result`.

I made the function `volatile` -- so it recalculates whenever the spreadsheet does. This matches how `RAND()` works  in Excel. If you don't want that -- remove the line `Application.Volatile`.

A Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If i want the result to be in separate cells? i.e each number to be in a different cell, in column B as your screenshot?

Comment: Possibilities: 1) it is possible to have the function return an array and use it as an array formula 2) it is possible to use a sub rather than a function if you pass the sub the range where the output is to be. 3) It is possible to leave it as is and use spreadsheet functions to extract the successive digits. 4) It is possible to bypass VBA entirely. In B2 enter 1 and then in C2 enter the formula `=IF(B2=1,IF(RAND()<=0.23,0,1),IF(RAND()>0.86,1,0))` and copy it for the desired number of columns, though without modification this wouldn't update with A2.

Answer (score 2):

This translates your English to **VBA**

```
Sub Jona()
   Dim Current As Long, Yearr As Long
   Dim u As Double, Result As String

   Current = 1
   Yearr = 0

   While Yearr < Range("A2").Value
      u = Rnd()
      If Current = 1 And u <= 0.23 Then
         Current = 0
      ElseIf Current = 0 And u > 0.86 Then
         Current = 1
      End If
      Yearr = Yearr + 1
      Result = Result & Current
   Wend

   MsgBox Result
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice -- when I saw your code I realized that I had accidentally shadowed `Year()` in an essentially harmless but nevertheless ill-advised way.

Comment: Also If i want the result to appear in a range in excel(for example in column C) what I have to write in the last sentence?